# How can I save the positions of elements on an array using the elements of another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It's kinda difficult to put my question more clear than it is, but i'll try to explain it better here.

I have three arrays:

```
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344]
var nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344]
var posiciones = [];
```

I want that each element of *nums* gets checked using each element on *nums4* and the position of those elements on *nums* gets pushed in on *posiciones*.

Here's what I made so far, but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344]
var nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344]
var posiciones = [];
    var pos = nums.indexOf(nums4[0])

    for (var io = 0; pos != -1 ;)
    /*while (pos != -1)*/
    {
        posiciones.push(pos);
        if(nums4.indexOf(nums4[io], pos + 1) == -1)
        {
        io++;
        }
        pos = nums.indexOf(nums4[io],pos + 1);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < posiciones.length; i++)
    {
        posiciones[i]++;
    }
```

I don't know if I made myself clear with this question, since English is not my mother language, but if you can explain me how to do it, I'll be more than grateful.

Edit: The answer should be:

```
var posiciones = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

but instead of it the answer provided by the code is:

```
var posiciones = [2, 3, 5, 10]
```

Also, I edited the numbers provided because depending of the numbers and answer is provided and I looked for numbers that doesn't give me the desired answers.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: You placed a backtick (`\``) after the `nums4` array. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Updated for your new data set, but note that your expected result is wrong, it should be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]` unless your logic is very, very different from what you've said, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064436/javasript-how-can-i-save-the-positions-of-elements-on-an-array-using-the-eleme#comment96877281_55064436). If you want the first entry to be at "index" 1 instead of index 0, just use `+ 1` when saving the index in the examples below)*

> I want that each element of nums gets checked using each element on nums4 and the position of those elements on nums gets pushed in on posiciones.

For such a small data set, for the `nums4` check I'd probably just use `includes`. (For a larger data set, I'd make a `Map` or similar to avoid constantly rescanning.)

For the main loop, perhaps `forEach`:

```js
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344]
var nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344]
var posiciones = [];
nums.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (nums4.includes(value)) {
        posiciones.push(index);
    }
});

console.log(posiciones);
```

Or starting with "index" 1 instead of 0:

```js
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344]
var nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344]
var posiciones = [];
nums.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (nums4.includes(value)) {
        posiciones.push(index + 1); // + 1 to make it 1-based
    }
});

console.log(posiciones);
```

---

Or just a simple `for` loop:

```js
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344]
var nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344]
var posiciones = [];
for (let index = 0; index < nums.length; ++index) {
    if (nums4.includes(nums[index])) {
        posiciones.push(index);
    }
}

console.log(posiciones);
```

Or starting with "index" 1 instead of 0:

```js
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344]
var nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344]
var posiciones = [];
for (let index = 0; index < nums.length; ++index) {
    if (nums4.includes(nums[index])) {
        posiciones.push(index + 1); // + 1 to make it 1-based
    }
}

console.log(posiciones);
```

---

Or if you want to go all FP, `map` and `filter`:

```js
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344]
var nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344]
var posiciones = nums.map((value, index) => nums4.includes(value) ? index : null).filter(v => v !== null);

console.log(posiciones);
```

Or starting with "index" 1 instead of 0:

```js
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344]
var nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344]
var posiciones = nums.map((value, index) => nums4.includes(value) ? index + 1 : null).filter(v => v !== null);
// + 1 to make it 1-based -----------------------------------------------^^^^

console.log(posiciones);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the nums4 element was not found in nums, you will get -1.

```js
var nums = [10, 3, 45, 44, 34, 4, 23, 44, 23, 254]
var nums4 = [44, 34, 4, 44, 254]
var posiciones = nums4.map(n => nums.indexOf(n));

console.log(posiciones);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and map the shifted indices.

```js
var nums = [431, 324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3441, 3214, 4344],
    nums4 = [324, 4344, 4324, 4344, 4324, 4444, 3214, 4344],
    pos = nums.reduce((m, v, i) => m.set(v, [...(m.get(v) || []), i + 1]), new Map);
    posiciones = nums4.map(v => pos.get(v).shift());

console.log(...posiciones);
```